# Cordova Won't Install

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I was having a problem with my project and I decided to uninstall and reinstall cordova as I have in the past which sometimes fixes my problem.

I can not install cordova anymore. I get this message:

> npm install cordova npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version
>   is no longer supp
>   orted. Please update to 4.x or newer npm WARN The package firebase is
>   included as both a dev and producti
>   on dependency. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   fsevents@1.2.4 (node
>   _modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform f
>   or fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"o
>   s":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> cordova@8.0.0 added 1 package from 1 contributor, removed 2 packages, updated 4 pa
>   ckages and audited 13057 packages in 40.069s found 6 vulnerabilities
>   (1 low, 5 moderate)   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit`
>   for details

So I try npm audit fix:

> npm audit fix npm WARN The package firebase is included as both a dev
>   and production dependency. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> up to date in 13.619s fixed 0 of 6 vulnerabilities in 13057 scanned
>   packages  6 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be
>   updated

When I try to see if Cordova installed:

> cordova --version bash: /c/Users/computer/AppData/Roaming/npm/cordova:
>   No such file or
>   directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing cordova on my Windows 10 machine using GitBash I needed to do this:

> npm install -g cordova

I had not used the -g when trying to install.